# indiscrete topology, connectivity

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I am trying to figure out why $(X, \mathcal{O}_{indis})$, where $\mathcal{O}_{indis}$ is the indiscrete topology, is connected for every
set $X$.

Furthermore, I am trying to understand why $\{ s \} \subset (X, \mathcal{O})$
is connected for any topological space.

Thank you!

Comment: What is your definition of connected?

Comment: Is it clear to you that a topological space that is equipped with indiscrete topology is connected?